# How do I configure a Gigabyte RTX 4070 on a 22.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I'm trying to install/configure a new Gigabyte **RTX 4070** on a Z490 motherboard running an **Ubuntu 22.04**. I have also installed nvidia drivers **535** with software-properties-gtk 
Can watch HD videos on Youtube with no problems but fps on my only game (X-plane) are terrible (0,0.. fps). The results with glxgears is the same (60 FPS).

**So, is it a compatibilty issue between my 4.0 GPU / 3.0 motherboard, or an installation/configuration problem ?**

Thank you.

Here are some other infos:

**$ hwinfo --gfxcard |grep "Vendor"**
`Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"`
`SubVendor: pci 0x1458 "Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd"`
**$ lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d"**
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2786 (rev a1)`

**$ lshw -c video**
`*-display`
   `description: VGA compatible controller`
          `product: NVIDIA Corporation`
          `vendor: NVIDIA Corporation`
          `physical id: 0`
          `bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0`
          `version: a1`
          `width: 64 bits`
          `clock: 33MHz`
          `capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom`
          `configuration: driver=nvidia latency=`0
          `resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:143 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff memory:4010000000-4011ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff`
`*-graphics`
          `product: EFI VGA`
          `physical id: 2`
          `logical name: /dev/fb0`
          `capabilities: fb`
          `configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080`

**$ glxinfo |grep "direct rendering"**
`direct rendering: Yes`

**$ nvidia-smi**
`Sat Sep  9 05:21:45 2023`
`+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+`
`| NVIDIA-SMI 535.86.05              Driver Version: 535.86.05    CUDA Version: 12.2     |`
`|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+`
`| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |`
`| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |`
`|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |`
`|=========================================+======================+======================|`
`|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |`
`|  0%   34C    P8               9W / 200W |    339MiB / 12282MiB |      4%      Default |`
`|                                         |                      |                  N/A |`
`+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+`

Comment: I've a similar issue.
It looks like that the nvidia-Drivers for Linux are buggy and don't work well with the RTX 4070 (NVIDIA Corporation Device 2786 (rev a1)
). In my case, nvidia-smi doesn't detect that card even though it is seen on the PCIe-Bus and works well under Windows.
I even tried the 545-beta drivers... [NVIDIA-drivers v535 aren't working with RTX 4070 - Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2387248#p2387248)